# Loading a CLOB with a KEY

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-loader

I need to load by using SQL Loader, a list of CLOB into a table.
What I generally do is to have a file LIST.DAT containing the list of CLOB on the Server:

```
FILE1
FILE2
FILE3
```

and then having a ctl like this:

```
load data
 infile "LIST.DAT" stream
 badfile "LIST.BAD"
 append
into table MYTABLE
fields terminated by ','
trailing nullcols
(id_seq sequence(max,1),
 file_name       char(150),
 file_lob lobfile(file_name) terminated by eof
)
```

so as to get something like this into MYTABLE:

```
ID_SEQ  CLOB
1       FILE1
2       FILE2
3       FILE3
```

Now I need to load every CLOB with a KEY arriving externally, that is I would like to have into MYTABLE something like:

```
ID_SEQ   KEY    CLOB
1        34     FILE1
2        22     FILE2
3        78     FILE3
```

In this case, how should I receive for every CLOB its own KEY on the Server and how could I then load both of them?

Oracle 10g

Thank you

Comment: So the KEY column is an external identifier of the CLOB column? The obvious answer is that the two columns arrive in the same DAT file and you just change the loader script accordingly. However, the existence of this question suggests your files aren't structured that way. You need to explain a bit more about the data you're trying to load. And especially, if the two columns aren't in the same file how do you know which KEY belongs with which CLOB?

Comment: And you're really still on 10g?

Comment: that's is the problem! Someone should send me a CLOB and this KEY linked to it, but I don't know which is the better way to get it. Two separated files? And how to link them?

Comment: *"Two separated files? "* No. One file with two columns. The data owner is responsible for defining the linkage between them. This is not a programming question, this is a matter for you to resolve with whoever is sending you the source data.